# Why can any inner product in $\Bbb{R}^n$ be represented in a general form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why can any inner $\langle\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle$ Product in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ be rewritten as $x^{T}Ay$ (so it can be rewritten as the standard euclidean product)?  I know that $$
\langle\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \mathbf{e}_{i}, \sum_{j=1}^{n} y_{j} \mathbf{e}_{j}\right\rangle=\sum_{i, j=1}^{n} x_{i} y_{j}\left\langle\mathbf{e}_{i}, \mathbf{e}_{j}\right\rangle
$$
where $\bf{e}$ denotes the canonical basis. But doesn't that only say that matrix $A$ can be the identity matrix, since the inner product of the orthonormal basis vectors is always $0$ or $1$?

Comment: an inner product cant be rewritten as $x^TAy$, unless $A$ is assumed to be symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: @Syd I think you have it backwards. An inner product can always be written as $x^{T}Ay$ for some matrix $A$. Then the properties of an inner product will allow you to **conclude** that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basis vectors $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \dots, \mathbf e_n$ are only orthonormal with respect to the **standard** inner product. If $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is some other inner product, then you don't know what $\langle \mathbf e_i, \mathbf e_j\rangle$ is. All you can do is define $A_{ij} = \langle \mathbf e_i, \mathbf e_j\rangle$, and then what you've done shows that $$\langle \mathbf x , \mathbf y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i y_j A_{ij} = \mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A \mathbf y.$$ (From properties of inner products, you can deduce other things. For instance, if you know that $\langle \mathbf x , \mathbf y \rangle = \langle \mathbf y, \mathbf x\rangle$ for all $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$, then you know that $\langle \mathbf e_i, \mathbf e_j\rangle = \langle \mathbf e_j, \mathbf e_i\rangle$. Therefore $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$, so $A$ is symmetric.)

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response!